# InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

I have a web service method defined as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable GetPrintingList()
{
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT = CommonModule.Connection.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT QUERY");
    return (DT);
}
```

when consuming this webservice method I am getting exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There was an error generating the
>   XML document.

after execution of select query I am getting 2 rows and 15 columns in `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable GetPrintingList()
{
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT = CommonModule.Connection.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT QUERY");
    DT.TableName = "tableNameHere";
    return (DT);
}
```

Comment: It is working after adding Table Name but getting same error when no any data come in SQL query.